# How to set up a Wifi Hotspot on ubuntu14.04 and set 192.168.42.1 as wlan0 address?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I have tried to set up a hotspot on ubuntu14.04. My `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` file is shown below.

```
[connection]
id=hotspott
uuid=03eb0f63-e766-41df-bc04-0f30740f6841
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=machCochin
mode=ap
mac-address=B0:C0:90:68:EE:73

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
address1=192.168.42.1/24,192.168.42.1
```

This creates the hotspot but I can't connect to the network. I have tried by replacing ipv4 section to `method=shared` and at that time I can join to the network from my phone but it assigned with a dynamic address.

How to create static IP for wlan0 when working as hotspot?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can't connect because, *NetworkManager* creates an **ad-hoc** AP.

I would recommend to use `create_ap`. It's a simple script that simplifies the use of `hostapd` and *iptables* and *dnsmasq*.

Just clone it at github with:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git
```

Then you need some dependancies, if you don't have them installed:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables dnsmasq hostapd
```

And then, you can run it from the create_ap directory:

```
cd create_ap
sudo ./create_ap -w 2 wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

You can change it's configuration to get 192.168.42.1 as wlan IP. If I understand you correctly, use the `--gateway 192.168.42.1` switch to `create_ap`